# Unable to start docker programmatically in Mac OS with Java TestNG Selenium Grid

Tags: java, docker, automated-tests, selenium-grid

Have spent over 8 hours trying trying to fix this problem with zero success.  I want to start and stop docker desktop programmatically. I know it's possible as a window user **but I cannot find any how to do this with mac operating system (I have checked)**.  I found something that might work but there I are elements of the  java code with Selenium Grid I don't understand.  It might be ignorance on my part as a novice but I just want to fix this as I'm sure it's simple.

I decided to run the code anyway because I could find a solution if I understood the error message.  I ran the code it failed but I got no error message.

I'm a novice with Selenium Grid with Java so any feedback will be appreciated.

this is piece of code I seem to be having a problem with.

**The user.dir seems to be mean some sort of user directory? But what directory are they specifically talking about?  I have no idea.**

I will show a snippet 1st and then the full code.

```
public class TestBase {

     private static final String SETUP_DOCKER_SCRIPT_FILE = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/dockerup.sh";
        private static final String SCALE_CHROME_FILE = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/docker_scale.sh";
        private static final String TEAR_DOWN_SCRIPT_FILE = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/dockerdown.sh";
        private static final String EXPECTED_MESSAGE = "The node is registered to the hub and ready to use";
        public static ThreadLocal<RemoteWebDriver> remoteWebDriver = new ThreadLocal<RemoteWebDriver>();
```

Here is the code in full:

```
package remoteTesting.dockerValidation1;


import static utils.StartStopDockerContainer.execute;//this is a imported file from the utils package

import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;

public class TestBase {

     private static final String SETUP_DOCKER_SCRIPT_FILE = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/dockerup.sh";
        private static final String SCALE_CHROME_FILE = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/docker_scale.sh";
        private static final String TEAR_DOWN_SCRIPT_FILE = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/dockerdown.sh";
        private static final String EXPECTED_MESSAGE = "The node is registered to the hub and ready to use";
        public static ThreadLocal<RemoteWebDriver> remoteWebDriver = new ThreadLocal<RemoteWebDriver>();

        @BeforeSuite
        public void setUp() {
            execute(SETUP_DOCKER_SCRIPT_FILE, EXPECTED_MESSAGE);
            execute(SCALE_CHROME_FILE, true);
        }

        @BeforeClass
        public void beforeTest() throws Exception {
            URL url = new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub");
            DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
            remoteWebDriver.set(new RemoteWebDriver(url, desiredCapabilities));
        }

        @AfterClass
        public void tearDown() {
            remoteWebDriver.get().close();
        }

        @AfterSuite
        public void afterTest() {
            execute(TEAR_DOWN_SCRIPT_FILE, true);
        }
}
```